# Controling case lighting from Ubuntu

Tags: bash, python, motherboard

I'd like control my computer case leds from Ubuntu 16, in order to see a semaphore indicating the machine and processes status.

My mobo is a Gigabyte Aorus X399 Gaming 7 and my case is a Phanteks Enthoo Luxe.

How could I change the case leds color? Changing mobo leds color, or turning it on/off would be also great.

Is there any linux application, python script, bash script ... to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do the leds illuminate at all? Some place there is a device that controls those lights.

How you might interface with that device, depends what it is, and how it is connected. Might it be a usb interface? or on some proprietary bus? or maybe its a serial connection?  I would start by trying to ID the device that drives the LEDs. You might try  looking at the output of:
`sudo dmidecode`
and or:
`sudo lshw`
or:
`sudo lsusb`

perhaps youll see an intuitively named category that makes sense describing the device in dmidecode, such as "lights", "controller", or "LEDs". Or maybe something else describes the MotherBoard LED lighting system.  Once you ID the device that drives the lights, it will be easier to know how to control that hardware.

I see that there is an interface for LED string lights... are you using those lights or is that hardware you have? The LEDs look like neopixels, which include an integrated driver, and run as a serial connections. If that is correct, you could control the lights by writing a program that defines the total number of LEDs, then sends colour, brightness, addressing, and timing info to the LEDS.

Try to ID the hardware that drives the LEDs, and Ill try to assist further.
Alternatively, post output from dmidecode, lshw, and lsusb.